# AngularJS client side function?

Tags: angularjs

I have two ng-models that are form input fields.  Later in the form, I do this to display a total numeric value of the two models:

```
{{field1--field2}}
```

This adds the two fields.  I'd like to capture the result and use it in a couple of other places.  What is the best way to do this in Angular without using a JS file?

Comment: do you allowed to use <script> ?

Comment: I'm not currently but can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a misuse (or underuse) of Angular. Angular is a platform for MVVM-style apps, and without a backing JS - to define the Model and the ViewModel - it is next to useless.

Nevertheless, you could define variable on the scope from within the View, like so:

```
<input ng-model="field1" ng-change="sum = field1 -- field2">
<input ng-model="field2" ng-change="sum = field1 -- field2">

{{sum}}
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fgq6k53tl1G7XpItTgW2?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

use a hidden input and set `total` to `field1--field2` as,  {{ total = field1--field2 }}

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ total = field1--field2 }}" />
```

then use `total`

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NLg1MC3YuCHqJIIn1bLr?p=preview)

Comment: This is less efficient approach than `ng-change`, since it will calculate `total` on *every* digest cycle, whether related to `field1`/`field2` or not